# Большое количество элементов в активити

Tags: java, android

Проблема в следующем, в экран своей активити разместил слишком много элементов (разного типа), из за чего если в 4-м элементе много значений(список к примеру) то элемент который расположен ниже в активити уже не отображается.
Я так понимаю нужно добавить Scroll или же есть какое то другое альтернативное решение вопроса?

Comment: Что за элементы? Если однотипные, используйте `RecyclerView`. Если нет - `ScrollView`. Все зависит от того, что Вам необходимо.

Comment: Сколько элементов?

Comment: @post_zeew 9 элементов, 8 из которых TextView и 1 WebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берете Ваш `xml`, где находятся Ваши элементы и делаете примерно следующим образом:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    //Ваши элементы TextView, WebView не важно.

   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/595829/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment803656_595829) было выяснено, что на экране размещены 8 `TextView` и `WebView`.

В этом случае целесообразно обернуть элементы в `ScrollView`.